# Equivalent C calloc in C++ for 2d array

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I found this code (C code) about a maze generator and i would like to use it in C++ :

```
{
    int x, y; //Node position - little waste of memory, but it allows faster generation
    void *parent; //Pointer to parent node
    char c; //Character to be displayed
    char dirs; //Directions that still haven't been explored
} Node;

Node *nodes; //Nodes array
int width, height; //Maze dimensions


int init( )
{
    int i, j;
    Node *n;
    
    //Allocate memory for maze
    nodes = calloc( width * height, sizeof( Node ) );
    if ( nodes == NULL ) return 1;
        
    //Setup crucial nodes
    for ( i = 0; i < width; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < height; j++ )
        {
            n = nodes + i + j * width;
            if ( i * j % 2 ) 
            {
                n->x = i;
                n->y = j;
                n->dirs = 15; //Assume that all directions can be explored (4 youngest bits set)
                n->c = ' '; 
            }
            else n->c = '#'; //Add walls between nodes
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the problem comes frome the line `nodes = calloc( width * height, sizeof( Node ) );`
How can i change it for a C++ code? I would like as possible to avoid to use `new` as all the code is big.

Comment: What does "avoid use of `new`" mean here? If it's big, it's big, and `new` vs. `calloc` doesn't change anything. `new` is just C++'s version of same.

Comment: For bit field, I prefer to use hexadecimal representation (or binary one) instead of decimal one, so `0x0F` or `0b1111` instead of `15`

Comment: @Jarod42 The hex notation tends to be more readable, but any strange numerical value without explanation is problematic. This should probably be `DIR_ALL` where that's `DIR_A | DIR_B | DIR_C | DIR_D ...`. Those can be defined in an `enum` like `DIR_A = 1 << 0, DIR_B = 1 << 1, ...`

Answer (score 1):

This is C++ so set `calloc` aside and use `new[]`:

```
Node *n = new Node[width * height];
```

Even better, `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Node> n(width * height);
```

Where in both cases it's as easy as:

```
auto& node = n[i + j * width];
```

To access individual elements.

You'll also want to make a proper constructor for your `Node` that sets up those pointers, or at least gives them safe defaults. In that case it might be easier to add them to the vector as you go, like:

```
 std::vector<Node> n; // Start empty

 // Inside the loops...
 n.emplace_back(i, j, nullptr, ' ', 15);
```

Comment: The equivalent of `calloc` is `new Node[width * height]()` (note the parenthesis at the end).